# application mode not support pyflink on yarn

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

command:
/space/flink/bin/flink run-application -t yarn-application -Dyarn.application.name=kafka-hive --pyFiles /space/testAirflow/airflow/dags/ -py /space/testAirflow/airflow/dags/chloe/kafka_to_hive_1.py

flink throw a Exception :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Should only have one jar

Does application mode not support pyflink?

Answer (score 1):

It is [not supported in <1.13](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-22871) and was supposedly [fixed in Flink 1.14.4](https://github.com/apache/flink/commit/5f99c42d27ad6b42df70c16810029ade365c9495). Sad.